# Can't connect to SQL Server from Node

Tags: sql-server, node.js

I use these versions:

```
node v4.7.3
mssql v3.2.1
```

I use mssql module to connect server, the doc for mssql is [here](https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql/blob/1893969195045a250f0fdeeb2de7f30dcf6689ad/README.md).

SQL server is run on Windows, I run the following command in Windows system to confirm the status of SQL server:

```
> netstat -ano | findstr 1433
 TCP    0.0.0.0:1433           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1452
 TCP    127.0.0.1:1433         127.0.0.1:50093        ESTABLISHED     1452
 TCP    127.0.0.1:50093        127.0.0.1:1433         ESTABLISHED     3636
```

Then I use `nc` to test the port for server:

```
$ nc -z msserver 1433
Connection to msserver port 1433 [tcp/ms-sql-s] succeeded!
```

which indicates that I can connect the port.

However, I can't connect the server by `mssql` module with the following config:

```
{
  user: 'sa',
  password: 'pwd',
  server: 'msserver',
  port: '1433',
  database: 'dbname',
  pool: {
    max: 10,
    min: 0,
    idleTimeoutMillis: 30000,
  },
  requestTimeout: 0,
  connectionTimeout: 15000,
  debug: true,
}
```

I use `debug: true` to get the debug info as follows:

```
connected to msserver:1433

Sent
  type:0x12(PRELOGIN), status:0x01(EOM), length:0x002F, spid:0x0000, packetId:0x01, window:0x00
  PreLogin - version:0.0.0.1 1, encryption:0x02(NOT_SUP), instopt:0x00, threadId:0x00000000, mars:0x00(OFF)
State change: Connecting -> SentPrelogin
socket ended
State change: SentPrelogin -> Final
connection to msserver:1433 closed
State is already Final
```

My code is here:

```
mssql.connect(config.mssql).then(function() {
  console.log('connected');
  new mssql.Request().query('select top 1 * from qmx.dbo.QMXStockPool order by ID desc', (err, records) => {
    console.log(err, records);
  });
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

no output, no error, finished soon.

Comment: Your code doesn't do anything except login. The capture doesn't show anything, except a login.  Your code worked. What is the problem? Have you tried executing a query? Can you connect to the server from SSMS or VSCode with those settings?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I print log info 'connected' or err, but no output after the program finished.

Comment: What did you expect? You connect, the connection succeeds and prints `connected`. If you don't execute a query, you won't see anything else

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I run a query, but it still no output. The callback function did not run.

Comment: @lutaoact if your query has a problem, *post the query*. Why did you ask about the connection, when you can see that it has already succeeded? Besides - how do you know that the query returns results? Did you try it with SSMS or VS Code or any other tool?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Could not connect because the maximum number of ‘4’ user connections has already been reached. I solved it and thank you all the time. The node module `mssql` did not give any error, I found the error log on the database server.

Comment: This error means that the maximum number of connections was changed explicitly. Normally, there is no limit.  Check [Error while connecting to SQL Server – “Could not connect because the maximum number of ‘1’ user connections has already been reached.”](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dataaccesstechnologies/2015/07/21/error-while-connecting-to-sql-server-could-not-connect-because-the-maximum-number-of-1-user-connections-has-already-been-reached/). It shows how to reset the value from the command line. You can also reset it from SSMS, in the Server's Properties, Connections tab. Default is 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, it appears that this error was logged in SQL Server's Error log file:

> Could not connect because the maximum number of ‘4’ user connections has already been reached.

This means that someone explicitly set a maximum concurrent connection limit. The default is unlimited connections.

The solution is to change the value back to the default 0 = unmlimited. The GUI way is to open SSMS, go to the `Connections` tab in the server's properties and set `Maximum number of concurrent connections` back to 0.
[image]

The other option, described in [Error while connecting to SQL Server – “Could not connect because the maximum number of ‘1’ user connections has already been reached.”](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dataaccesstechnologies/2015/07/21/error-while-connecting-to-sql-server-could-not-connect-because-the-maximum-number-of-1-user-connections-has-already-been-reached/) and numerous other articles, is to connect from the command line using `sqlcmd` and change the configuration setting :

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
go 

reconfigure 
go 

sp_configure 'user connections', 0  
go 

reconfigure 
go
```